# How do i use localStorage for an active link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to keep the focus CSS(basically, an active link CSS) on any link even after a page refresh. before I added the local storage snippet it worked, and it worked because the links I was switching to were '#' and didn't refresh upon click, I am using jquery. right now, nothing works.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript ">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li a').click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem("clicked", $(this).attr("id"));
    });
    var foocus = localStorage.getItem("clicked") || "home"; //<default
    $('li a').removeClass("foocus");
    $("#" + foocus).addClass("foocus");
    });
    });
</script>
```

HTML code

```
<div class="main-nav ">
                <a href=" " class="logo "><span><img src="images/logo.svg " alt=" "></span><span class="logo-text ">N</span></a>
                <ul class="main-menu ">
                    <li id="home">
                        <a href="index.html "><img class="nav-items " src="images/home.svg " alt=" "><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="# "><img class="nav-items " src="images/male.svg " alt=" "><span>Pas</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="# "><img class="nav-items " src="images/doctor.svg " alt=" "><span>Dors</span> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="# "><img class="nav-items " src="images/lab.svg " alt=" "><span>Lab Tests</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.main-nav ul li a {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: 350;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.main-nav ul li a span:hover {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.foocus {
    background: #8BC2A1;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    width: 168px;
    height: 38px;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to store the id of the `a` tag that has been clicked but none have any id value set for them.  If I run the page, the local storage setting is `clicked:undefined`.  Try adding `id` to each `a` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not targeting the correct id `attr` when clicking on an `li` item in your menu. Also, you need to removeClass `foocus` on all `li's` and `addClass` to the clicked `li` only in your click function.

I have fixed up your code (HTML, jQuery) and is working as expected now. Replace your `code` this below and it should work fine as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.main-menu > li').click(function() {
    //set localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("clicked", $(this).attr("id"))
    //remove from all li
    $('li').removeClass("foocus")
    //Add class to the clicked li
    $(this).addClass("foocus")
  });

  //get class on load
  var foocus = localStorage.getItem("clicked")
  foocus ? $("#" + foocus).addClass("foocus") : $('#home').addClass("foocus")
})
```

**Working Demo:** (Test this code in your browser since stack-overflow snippet does not support localStorage)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.main-menu > li').click(function() {
    //set localStorage
    //localStorage.setItem("clicked", $(this).attr("id"))
    //remove from all li
    $('li').removeClass("foocus")
    //Add class to the clicked li
    $(this).addClass("foocus")
  })

  //get class on load
  //var foocus = window.localStorage.getItem("clicked")
  //foocus ? $("#" + foocus).addClass("foocus") : $('#home').addClass("foocus")
})
```

```css
.main-nav ul li a {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-weight: 350;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.main-nav ul li a span:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.foocus {
  background: #8BC2A1;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  width: 168px;
  height: 38px;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-nav">
  <a href=" " class="logo "><span><img src="images/logo.svg " alt=" "></span><span class="logo-text">N</span></a>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li id="home">
      <a href="#"><img class="nav-items " src="images/home.svg" alt=" "><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="pas">
      <a href="# "><img class="nav-items " src="images/male.svg " alt=" "><span>Pas</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="dors">
      <a href="# "><img class="nav-items " src="images/doctor.svg " alt=" "><span>Dors</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li id="labtests">
      <a href="# "><img class="nav-items " src="images/lab.svg " alt=" "><span>Lab Tests</span> </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```